# mysqli_stmt_bind_param and mysqli_stmt_execute expect parameter to be mysqli_stmt, boolean

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

User clicks button:

```
<input type="image" src="img/like.png" alt="Like" value="Like">
<input type="hidden" name="IP" value="<?php $_SERVER ["REMOTE_ADDR"] ?>">
```

Save into database (errors are in comments):

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        $connection = mysqli_connect ($servername, $username, $password);
        $statement = mysqli_prepare ($connection, "INSERT INTO Like (User, PageId) VALUES (?, ?)");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($statement, "si", $_POST[IP], $_GET[id]); 
        //mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean
        mysqli_stmt_execute ($statement);
       //mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Display like amount:

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect ($servername, $username, $password);
    $statement = mysqli_prepare ($connection, "SELECT * FROM Like WHERE PageId=$_GET[id];");
?>
```

Everything looks right to me, but I'm new and have a hard time learning PHP/SQL.

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: @NanaPartykar, the errors are posted inside the code blocks next to the corresponding lines

Comment: Oh Yes. It was not visualized to me.

Comment: Also there's a table called `Like` (a reserved keyword)... which may cause problems unless escaped.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it

Answer (score 3):

The error is found by looking at your connection, You don't connect to a database, what you have is:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect ($servername, $username, $password);
```

Where what you need is:

```
$database = 'my_db';
$connection = mysqli_connect ($servername, $username, $password, $database);
```

Comment: Ah, tyvm. Brain is tired after coding all weekend.

Comment: @Iphd, no problem, one suggestion however, I'd look into the OOP version of mysqli rather than the pragmatic version you are using, it is much more robust and re-usable :P

Answer (score 3):

Issue in your code is that, you are using input field as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="IP" value="<?php $_SERVER ["REMOTE_ADDR"] ?>">
```

This should be like that:

```
<input type="hidden" name="IP" value="<?php echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; ?>">
```

**or**

```
<input type="hidden" name="IP" value="<?=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]?>">
```

**Issue:**

You are using empty input field in `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`

Comment: `value="<?php echo $_SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?>"`

Comment: @iphd: if these answer solved your problem than chose the best answer and mark as accepted otherwise people will assume you are still looking for solution...